# Power BI Calculated Column in DAX vs PowerQuery

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

What is the performance difference (if there is any at all) in:

1. When we create a calculated column in DAX after loading the data
2. When we create a calculated column in query editor itself

Answer (score 0):

As per my experience, calculated column in power query is more feasible as creating it in dax.....

Comment: Can you elaborate feasibly?  is it more performance efficient?

Comment: It really depends on what it is. Some things are much easier in one or the other.

Comment: the complex the calculation, the slower is your dax calculated column and as said @alexis it really depends on what you are trying to achieve.